# extbase - mapping from columns

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.x

I have two columns in the table article

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            XY\Products\Domain\Model\Product {
                mapping {
                    tableName = artikel

                    columns {
                        uuid.mapOnProperty = uuid
                        inactive.mapOnProperty = inactive
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have the set/get in the domain model. When I make a new object, i see and can set the `uuid` but with `inactive` it is not working. It worked in TYPO3 6 lts, but now with TYPO3 7 LTS the system says that the function `setInactive()` was not found.

I have deleted the cache by the flashes and in the install tool. What else can I do?

It seems like I do not need to extend the TCA because that does not exist for `uuid`. So that cannot be the reason and it worked before.

Comment: Can you post the signature of your model class, i.e. all the methods with their parameters and return types? Actual implementation is not necessary.

Comment: you need the TCA for that and you need the property with a correct annotation and the getters + setters.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was somewhere else. well, the autoloader of the domain model loads all files there. so if you have a product.php and nice people who make product.php-2015-05-23.php then php loads both and uses the second. And in the second was not the new get/set. gosh.